# NodeJs - how to get full path of url

Tags: node.js, express

**This is one of my routes:**

```
   module.exports = function(app)
 {
     router.route('/')
         .all(ctrl.SomeCtrl.all)
         .post(ctrl.SomeCtrl.post)
     router.route('/name/:name')
         .get(ctrl.SomeCtrl.getByName)
     router.route('/:id')
         .get(ctrl.SomeCtrl.getById)
         .put(ctrl.SomeCtrl.put)
         .delete(ctrl.SomeCtrl.delete)

     app.use('/api/my-api-path', router)
  }
```

In SomeCtrl.all, if I code for a

```
  res(req.url) // returns back ==> '/'.
```

I understand why that is because ".all" has router.route('/').

But, what I am trying to get is:

```
    '/api/my-api-path/'
```

Is there another req call I can make to get the full path w/o re-doing the way I set up my route?

Answer (score 1):

**Found the answer:**

```
  res.send(req.originalUrl);  // returns back ==> '/api/my-api-path/'
```